# Why href="tel:false" gives 32573 in phone dialer?

Tags: android, html

When clicked on this link from a mobile it opens dialer app with number showing as 32573, where does this 32573 come from? and if you make it "true" it shows 8783.

```
<a href="tel:false">Click to call</a>
```

Comment: Interesting. It is not 32768 which might be some signed int

Comment: that's really strange. I also cannot replicate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the numbers that correlate with the letters on a telephone keypad.

**Example**

555-TRUE = 555-8783